# Why is a DataFrame created with read_csv() different than another one created with DataFrame() with the same data?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, nan

Say there is a csv file as follows:

```
# data.csv
0,1,2,3,4
a,3.0,3.0,3.0,3.0,3.0
b,3.0,3.0,3.0,3.0,3.0
c,3.0,3.0,3.0,3.0,3.0
d,3.0,3.0,3.0,3.0,3.0
```

Now I create two dataframes: one from the csv file, another using `DataFrame()`. 
I expect both DataFrame to be equal.

```py
# Read the csv file into a pandas.DataFrame
A = pandas.read_csv('data.csv')

# Create (same?) dataframe by hand
B = pandas.DataFrame(3*numpy.ones((4,5)), index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
```

However, if I substract them, I obtain:

```py
print(A-B)
    0   1   2   3   4   0   1   2   3   4
a NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
b NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
c NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
d NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Any idea(s) why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataFrames are not equal, because in `A` are columns names strings, in `B` are integers.

So need convert integers columns to integers:

```
A = pandas.read_csv('data.csv').rename(columns=int)
```

Or convert `B` columns to strings:

```
B = pandas.DataFrame(3*numpy.ones((4,5)), index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']).rename(columns=str)
```